# AJAX post with absolute url to backend file

Tags: php, ajax, backend

I am working on an AJAX post from which needs to send data to a php file. This file is ONE located level above the domain root.

If my domain root is **/root_general/root_domain/**
The file php backend file is in **/root_general/**
I am trying to achieve this by using the `dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'])` url. But AJAX won't load the file, it tells me that the file wasn't found on this server. I am using Apache2 on Ubuntu and working with all permissions enabled.
How can I do it in other way? I need to put the file outside because it is supposed to be used by many different domains, and I think it wouldn't be clean to paste the same file inside every single domain root.

**Edit: some code**

When calling the file it's this way:

```
http[act].open('post',url,true);
```

Comment: Some code would be useful

Comment: @popnoodles So people vote negative. And no one gives a reason. I though questions where something where you GET information. If I knew it all I wouldn't have asked. Anyway, I asked with respect. All those negative votes make me only SMILE. I'm glad I'm not that negative. You asked for code without needing it? What was the purpose of it then? Hey thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use AJAX to access files on the server. You can use it only to access URLs. So what you need to do is point an URL to that file you want to access. You can give it own domain, you can copy it a few times or you can have symlinks point to it.

Comment: Well, I might have missed the part about script having to come from the domain you try to access as it wasn't really part of the topic http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

Comment: Yes thanks, but... how can I do what I was asking for, then? People gave me negative votes as if it were a silly question. But no one gives the answer. That's the funny stuff.

Comment: You're getting downvoted because instead of reading up when you're given a hint you start insulting people like if they're responsible for your lack of knowledge.